# Join two tables model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a SQL Server database with 2 tables. In the first table I have a column `categoryid` and I want to use `categoryName` from the second table.

```
public IQueryable<Car> Repeater1_GetData()
{
    ExEntities contex = new ExEntities();

    return contex.Cars.Include("Category");
}
```

I use this function to display data in list view but it returns `categoryId`. In Northwind database the same relation works ok. Where is the problem?

Comment: What Data Access Layer do you use? Entity framework? And how do you display it in listview? Elaborate, please.

Comment: Yes i use ado.net entity model and model binding

Comment: Can you add more code? And describe the both tables?

Comment: I am not sure that asp.net ListView provides nice column autogeneration options - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398790(v=vs.100).aspx , http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/603171/Dynamic-Columns-in-Listview. May be you should set correct templates for it to display the desired data?

Comment: Just list view with select method. 1st database CategoryId and CategoryName second database CarId and CarCategory. 1 to 1 relation. CarId and CategoryId are the 2 primery keys.

Comment: I tried with gridview but same result

Comment: What columns does it generate? And it(gridview or listview) won't probably expand any nested  complex objects by default.

Comment: The list view has item template and i display the result using <%# %>